# preg_replace not working :(

Tags: php, preg-replace

OK so I have this PHP script:

```
<?php

$stringz = "Dan likes to eat pears and his favorite color is green!";
$patterns = array("/pears/","/green/");
$string = preg_replace($patterns, '<b>\\1</b>', $stringz);
echo "<textarea rows='30' cols='100'>$string</textarea>";

?>
```

and when I run it I get this:
`Dan likes to eat <b></b> and his favorite color is <b></b>!`

The  is suppose to have a word in it... but it doesn't...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `\\1` for `\\0`.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you aren't explicitly capturing anything. `\\0` captures the entire match, of course, but in order to capture specific parts, you need to use capturing groups if you want to use `\\1`, `\\2`, `\\3`, etc. Change `$patterns` to this:

```
 $patterns = array("/(pears)/","/(green)/");
```

`()`'s denote capturing groups, and whatever value is captured inside of them is stored in the reference `\\n`, where `\\n` refers the the 1-indexed `n`th capturing group.

Comment: Actually you always capture the whole thing in `\0`, whether you have parenthesis groups or not.

Comment: Right, what I meant was he isn't *explicitly* capturing anything. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$patterns = array("/(pears)/","/(green)/");
```

?

`\\1` applies to a subject, which is whatever you have in parentheses.

Comment: /** @see [my comment on Alex's answer] */